# Difference between "will do" and "be doing"

Tags: future-tense

Here is a test i did. But now i'm confused with "will do" and "be doing". So anybody plz help me with it? Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

I searched on the web and found nothing.

Comment: Please post text and not images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Will means disposing or inclining, not decided plan.
The form 'verb + ~ing' can mean decided plan when the suffix '~ing' added to a verb with the context containing information of specific plan.

Answer (score -1):

"Will", among several other usages, is used to talk about predictions of the future and you are unsure if it will actually happen: For example: "What are you doing tomorrow?" "Well, maybe I will go shopping." You are guessing that you might do this but cannot say for sure.

One of the functions of the present continuous is for talking about future events that have been decided or planned. For example: "What are you doing tomorrow?" "I'm going shopping!" You have decided that this is what you are going to do. This is the same as "be going to", that is, "I'm going to (do something)". For example, "I'm going to watch a film this evening."

In your sentence, Bill has an appointment with his parents - a plan has been made - so the present continuous should be used. Note that "Bill will visit his parents tomorrow." (without the second sentence) is also grammatical but this means it is a prediction, not a decision, and Bill might or might not end up visiting his parents.